# Can't fetch rich text field from Strapi to Astro framework

Tags: markdown, strapi, astrojs

I am developing a headless blog using Astro framework and strapi headless CMS. I have a problem when fetching rich text field from Strapi to Astro. When I fetch body field with rich text format, it shows [object Object][object Object][object Object]. The code is given below.

Store.astro page

```
---
import Master from "../../layouts/MasterLayout.astro";

const title = "Store Bright Coding";

const response = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/api/courses? 
populate=image').then(res => res.json())
const courses = response.data

---

<Master {title}>
    <div class="row px-20">
        <div>
            <h1 class="text-5xl font-bold mt-10">Store</h1>
            <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-5 h-screen">
            {courses.map(({ attributes: {title, body, price, url, image, bodybody }}) => (

                <div class="flex bg-red-400 mt-20">
                    <div class="bg-blue-300">
                        <img class="w-full" src=    {`http://localhost:1337${image.data?.attributes?.formats?.thumbnail?.url}`}>
                        <div>
                            <h4>{title}</h4>
                            <p>{body}</p>
                            <p class="bg-red-400 mt-28">{bodybody}</p>
                            <h3>{`$${price}`}</h3>
                            <a href={url}>More...</a>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</Master>
```

I tried many ways to solve this. But I couldn't find any good solution for this. Please help me.

Comment: Can you post `console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data, null,2)`

Comment: If you see `[object Object]`, it generally means the JSON object you're trying to output is an object `{}` or array `[]`, not a primitive type like a string, number or boolean. So instead of doing `<p>{myObj}</p>`, you need to drill deeper, like `<p>{myObj.myField}</p>`... but to see which fields there are, see antokhio's comment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I took the solution from this example: look inside /blog/frontend/src/layouts/BlogPost.astro

https://github.com/Yusuke1998/blog

I still have a problem, this solution render the paragraphs, but not another elements, like .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).